# In the "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix" video game, what potion is used to sabotage Umbridge's speakers?

Tags: harry-potter

What potion is used in the video game *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* to sabotage Umbridge's Speakers? Does it have an official name?

Answer (score 11):

As can be seen from this screenshot [from your game](https://youtu.be/Bh3UIxNLY8Q?t=31), they used a

> "[Babbling Beverage](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Babbling_Beverage)".
>
> [image]

This potion also makes an appearance in Hogwarts Mystery

Answer (score 4):

In the video game the Patils say that it is Babbling Beverage. You can see this in [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w82z5bMrTqA&feature=youtu.be&t=490) of the video game walkthrough:

[image: Screenshot of video game walkthrough]

This potion is in fact mentioned once in the books. In Chapter Thirty-Two of *Order of the Phoenix* when Harry tried to tell Snape via code that Sirius was being tortured in the Department of Mysteries, Snape said:

> “Potter, when I
>   want nonsense shouted at me I shall give you a
>   Babbling Beverage.

Interestingly, there is no indication here that it can be used on objects as it is used in the game.

There is also a curse called the Babbling Curse mentioned in Chapter Ten of *Chamber of Secrets*, which presumably is something similar but in a curse instead of a potion. Lockhart is reputed to have cured someone from such a curse:

> Harry had been forced to play a simple Transylvanian villager whom Lockhart had cured of a Babbling Curse,